# What is the use of element.onresize?

Tags: javascript, html

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onresize) states that **element** has a property called **onresize**:

> Any element can be given an onresize attribute, however only the window object has a resize event. Resizing other elements (say by modifying the width or height of an img element using script) will not raise a resize event.

What is the point of `element.onresize` if resizing the element does not raise a resize event?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser.

> the onresize event is supported by the body, frameset, document and
>   window elements in Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari. They are
>   identical, they fire when the size of the browser window is changed.
>   Example 1 and 2 demonstrate it.

Reference: http://help.dottoro.com/ljorlllt.php

Comment: Is there even a way to get the "resize event" for a html element?

Comment: @Derek For doing some dynamic stuff in a JS game. Basically I want to resize an element based on the size of another element.